# change child-component checked state from parent-component synchronously fail

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

Please run the worked demo:

```js
let myCheckbox = Vue.component('my-checkbox', {
  template: `<div>
                <input type="checkbox" id="check1" :checked="checked" @change="change">{{checked}}            
            </div>`,
  props: ['checked'],
  methods: {
    change() {
      this.$emit('change', event.target.checked);
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    checked: true,
    count: 1
  },
  methods: {
    change(isChecked) {
      this.count++
        this.checked = isChecked
      if (this.count % 2 === 0) {
        // this.checked = !isChecked
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.checked = !isChecked
        }, 10);
      }
    }
  },
  components: {
    myCheckbox
  }
})
```

```css
span {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <my-checkbox :checked="checked" @change="change"></my-checkbox>
  When
  <span>{{count}}</span> is even your check will fail
</div>
```

however, if i change the synchronous operation to asynchronous operation in  `change` which means change

```
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.checked = !isChecked
        }, 10);
```

to

```
         this.checked = !isChecked
```

the demo is not going work because `checked` in the `check1` is not updated.

My question is

**I don't know why synchronous operation is not work!**

I guess there is a `promise` after the `change` to do the underlying operation and that's why `setTimeout` works.However, I am not sure and I didn't  find any explanation about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you tick the checkbox, the (native DOM) checkbox changes its appearance by adding the `v` (tick symbol).

When that tick happens, it emits the `change` event.

Notice that, at this point, the `checked` property from Vue has not been changed yet. This change will happen when "someone" picks up the `change` event and sets the `checked` accordingly. That's what the line 4 below does:

```
methods: {                      // 1
  change(isChecked) {           // 2
    this.count++;               // 3
    this.checked = isChecked    // 4
```

Now, when the `this.count` is even, in the code **without** `setTimeout`, you set right away `this.checked` to its previous value.

So, since Vue sees that `this.checked` did not change after the execution of the method, Vue understands there is no updating (no repainting) to do. That's why the ticked symbol (`v` above) remains (wrongly) ticked: Vue did not repaint the component.

As a proof, try the demo below. Notice the `updated` lifecycle handler never executes:

```js
let myCheckbox = Vue.component('my-checkbox', {
  template:
  `<div>
     <input type="checkbox" id="check1" :checked="checked" @change="change">{{checked}}            
   </div>`,
  props: ['checked'],
  methods: {
    change() {
      this.$emit('change', event.target.checked);
    }
  },
  // not executed because `checked` never changes (is always true)
  updated() { console.log('my-checkbox updated') }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    checked: true,
    count: 1
  },
  methods: {
    change(isChecked) {
      this.count++;
      this.checked = isChecked
      if (this.count % 2 === 0) {
        this.checked = !isChecked
      }
    }
  },
  components: {
    myCheckbox
  }
})
```

```css
span {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <my-checkbox :checked="checked" @change="change"></my-checkbox>
  When
  <span>{{count}}</span> is even your check will fail. - checked: <span>{{checked}}</span> - it never changes, always <b>true</b>, so my-checkbox <b>never</b> has to be updated/repainted.
</div>
```

Now, when you use the `setTimeout`, at the moment the `change(isChecked)` method has ended its execution, the `this.checked` **has changed**! Which triggers the repaint.

The thing is, **shortly after** the `setTimeout` handler executes, setting `this.checked` back to its original value. This triggers **another** repaint. Notice in the demo below, the updated hook is **executed twice** when `this.count` is even.

Finally, as a last note, the idiomatic way of doing that in Vue is [using `Vue.nextTick()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick), not a `setTimeout`:

```js
let myCheckbox = Vue.component('my-checkbox', {
  template:
  `<div>
     <input type="checkbox" id="check1" :checked="checked" @change="change">{{checked}}            
   </div>`,
  props: ['checked'],
  methods: {
    change() {
      this.$emit('change', event.target.checked);
    }
  },
  updated() { console.log('my-checkbox updated') },
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    checked: true,
    count: 1
  },
  methods: {
    change(isChecked) {
      this.count++;
      this.checked = isChecked
      if (this.count % 2 === 0) {
        Vue.nextTick(() => {
          this.checked = !isChecked
        });
        //setTimeout(() => {
        //  this.checked = !isChecked
        //}, 10);
      }
    }
  },
  components: {
    myCheckbox
  }
})
```

```css
span {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <my-checkbox :checked="checked" @change="change"></my-checkbox>
  When
  <span>{{count}}</span> is even the checked will be overridden. checked: <span>{{checked}}</span>
</div>
```